# an $n$-order cyclic group generated by $a$ has $a^{kn}=e$

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading introductory group theory and one of the proofs implicitly uses (but does not derive) the following:

> If a cyclic group $G$ is generated by $a$ and $|G|=n$ then $a^{kn}=e$.

This makes intuitive sense but I can't prove it, and the context it ([Chapter 4](http://abstract.ups.edu/)) appears in seems to be unrigorous.

> Let $G$ by a cyclic group of order $n$ and suppose that $a$ is a generator of $G$. Then $a^k=e$ if and only if $n$ divides $k$.
>
> By the division algorithm, $k=nq+r$ where $0\leq r < n$; hence,
>
> $$e=a^k=a^{nq}a^r=ea^r=a^r$$
>
> Since the smallest *positive* integer $m$ such that $a^m=e$ is $n$, $r=0$.

Doesn't the reduction $a^{nq}=e$ beg the question? And what is the justification for the last line?

What is a more complete proof of the claim?

Comment: Your remark  sets the `if` part, but they set  the `only if` part.

Comment: I left out the proof of the converse. I don't understand what "my remark" you are referring to.

Comment: ‘Doesn't the reduction $a^{nq}=e$ beg the question?’

Comment: The first claim is proved with *Lagrange's theorem*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't the reduction $a^{nq} = e$ beg the question" but I can try answering your second question. Think about what the order of an element in a group is. It is the smallest number of times I need to apply the group operation to the element in order to end up back at the identity element. In the question above the order of $a$ is going to be $n$ since it generates the entire group. Now think about what would happen if a generator of a group had an order smaller than the order of the group. It wouldn't produce all of the elements which is a contradiction.

Comment: I can give you an explicit example. Think about the group $Z_{5}$ under the operation of addition. The element of $Z_{5} = {0,1,2,3,4}$. In this group the element 1 is a generator of $Z_{5}$ since you can get any element in the group by applying the group operation enough times. Now think about what would happen if the order of 1 was anything other than 5. For example if the order of 1 was 4 then that means that we wouldn't be able to generate all the elements in the group because we would have $<1> = {1, 1^{2}, 1^{3}, 1^{4}}$. This contradicts the fact that 1 is a generator of the group.

Answer (score 1):

An easy conclusion form [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) is that if $|G| = n$ and $a \in G$ then $a^n = e$.

**Proof:**
Since $\langle a\rangle \subseteq G$, By Lagrange's theorem $|\langle a \rangle| = o(a) \mid |G| = n$.
Therefore $n = \alpha\cdot o(A)$ for some integer $\alpha$, and therefore $a^{n} = a^{\alpha \cdot o(A)} = (a^{o(a)})^{\alpha} = e^{\alpha} = e$.

From that of course it follows that $a^{nq} = (a^{n})^{q} = e^q = e$

Note that your case is even more simple, since if $a$ is a generator of $G$ then of course $o(a) = |G| \Rightarrow a^{|G|} = e$

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and $a\in G $ be its generator, then the smallest positive integer satisfying $a^x=e$ is $n$.

**Result:** If a cyclic group $G$ is generated by $a$ and $|G|=n$ then $a^{kn}=e$

**Proof:**

Since, $|G|=n$ and $G=<a>$ $\implies a^n=e$

Now, $a^{kn}= a^{n+...+n(k-times)} =a^n...a^n=e...e=e$

Q.E.D

Now the justification for the last line is as follows,

$e=a^r,\;\;0\le r<n \implies r=0$, for otherwise this will contradict the fact  that $|G|=n$.

Comment: What's your justification for the first line. Why does $a^{|G|}=e$?

Comment: @spraff If $|G|=n$ with generator $a\in G$, what would be the order of $a$?

Comment: By lagrange theorem $o(a) | |G|$, so $|G| = o(a)*k$ for an integer $k$, which means that $a^{|G|} = a^{o(a)k} = (a^{o(a)})^k = e^k = e$, here it is even easier to see since $o(a) = |G|$

Comment: @Math_QED If $O(a)=n$ it clearly implies that $a^n=e$ (without the rigour). It's straightforward from the definition.

Comment: Yes I know. Here you can apply the trick because the group is cyclic, but $a^{|G|} = e$ is a statement that always holds in finite groups, which I showed

Comment: I haven't got to Lagrange's theorem yet. Can we establish this on a much more elementary basis?

Comment: @spraff That is what I wanted to do, avoid bringing in Lagrange's theorem here. Since $a$ is the generator of $G$ with $|G|=n \implies o(a)=n$. Now by the definition of order of an element it follows $a^n=e$. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

**Definition**: If $g \in G$, then $o(g)$ is the smallest integer $k$ in $\mathbb{N_0}$ such that $g^k = e$. Then:

$$G =  \langle a \rangle$$
$$\Rightarrow o(a) = |G| = n$$
$$\Rightarrow a^n =e_G$$
$$\Rightarrow a^{nk} = (a^n)^k = (e_G)^k = e_G$$

Comment: My question is: how do you justify step 3?

Comment: You mean $o(a) = n \Rightarrow a^n = e$?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: What is your definition of order?

Comment: The number of elements in the group.

Comment: I mean $o(g)$ for $g \in G$, how do you define that?

Comment: The size of the set which is attached to the group operation. Examples: If $S$ is the symmetry group of the triangle, for example, $o(S)=|S|=6$. For integers modulo $n$, $|\mathbb{Z}_n|=n$.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: I still don't see how the implication is justified. I can convince myself intuitively, but not algebraically, and I'm trying to be rigorous with the algebra.

Comment: But it follows directly from the definition of order of an element in a group. Buy yourself a new textbook if you didn't encounter the definition of order (which I listed in my post). Or maybe you are confused with this? The order of an element in a group $\neq$ the order of the group, unless the group is cyclic (then this would be possible)